# Count number of levels of parents

Tags: apex, trigger

IB_ID__c String
IB_ID_CODE__c String
IB_Level__c Decimal

IB_ID_CODE__c= A
IB_ID__c = null
IB_Level__c=1

Now IB_ID__c is field with IB_ID_CODE__c of some other record.its kind of parent child but there is no relationship
e.g
Now when I have to insert record 2 with following details
IB_ID_CODE__c= B
IB_ID__c = A

IB_Level__c should show value 2

and when I have to insert record 3 with following details
IB_ID_CODE__c= B
IB_ID__c = C
IB_Level__c should show value 3

Ultimate parent will not have any IB_ID_CODE__c so level will be 1 as its on first level of hierarchy

I am trying to write following code but its not working.

Trigger

```
trigger UpdateIBLevel on IB_MM_Platform_Account__c (after insert, after update) {

    for(IB_MM_Platform_Account__c ib: trigger.new){
        if(ib.IB_ID__c!=null){
            UpdateIBLevelHandler ubl = new UpdateIBLevelHandler();
            ubl.getUltimateParent(ib.id);
        }
    }

}
```

Class

Class

```
public class UpdateIBLevelHandler {

       public  String getUltimateParent(id recId){

        String parentIBCode= [Select Id ,IB_ID__c,IB_ID_CODE__c,IB_Level__c from IB_MM_Platform_Account__c where Id=:recId].IB_ID__c;
        Decimal currentIBLevel= [Select Id ,IB_ID__c,IB_ID_CODE__c,IB_Level__c from IB_MM_Platform_Account__c where Id=:recId].IB_Level__c;
        System.debug('###### '+currentIBLevel);
        String currentIBID=parentIBCode;

        while(currentIBID!=null){

        currentIBID=[Select Id ,IB_ID__c,IB_ID_CODE__c,IB_Level__c from IB_MM_Platform_Account__c where IB_ID_CODE__c=:currentIBID].IB_ID__c;

        currentIBLevel++;
         System.debug('@@@@@@ '+parentIBCode);
        }
    return currentIBID;
    }
}
```

**Putting back to original question** (Please post new question so the context of this question is preserved for those having the same problem)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong ? it is giving me 101 soql error

Comment: I have no idea what most of your question means but the 101 SOQL error is because you are calling `getUltimateParent` in a `for loop` which in turn is doing 2 SOQL queries and has a SOQL query in a `while loop`.

Comment: I know that, i want to call that function recursively, but it is not exiting the while loop

Comment: you are getting 101 soql because you have a query in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are so many things one could say about the code, concept, etc your immediate issue is:

1. you set the value of **currentIBID**
2. You enter the while
3. You set **currentIBID** to the value of a query that gets the record that matches **currentIBID**

Thus, currentIBID is NEVER null and will continue to loop:

Even when you do fix the while loop, you are still executing a query inside a for loop by calling it in the trigger so it will appear again unless you resolve that as well

Comment: Thanks Eric, can you please look at my question and suggest a way to accomplish this. I want to call this function in such way that it gets IBID of parent and execute the logic to increase the level

Comment: this would be a different question. This question specifically deals with the To Many SOQL statements 101. Even when you do fix the while loop, you are still executing a query inside a for loop by calling it in the trigger so it will appear again unless you resolve that as well

Comment: Should I edit or post a new question?

Comment: @NickSFDC - Post a new question, mark this as the solution if it answered you to many queries question